# how can i trace an error or exception due to a trigger in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I need help to find the error in a trigger, the syntax is correct and i can add it to my table.
however when i insert data in this table through a software i get an error. when i disable the trigger the software can insert data. the problem is that software doesn't throw any exception.
how can i get the exact error, so i will be able to fix that trigger. is there an SQLserver error trace tool ? or Log Thank you very much

the trigger is after INSERT INTO statement if that could help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Profiler / Trace to trace user error messages.

Probably by far the most common error in triggers is assuming that the `inserted` and `deleted` tables will only contain 1 row so they then fail when a statement affects multiple rows. Does your trigger code do this?

Comment: no it's a simple triggers, that inseret into one table, some of the fields inserted in the original table. the problem is that the same trigger works with other same structured table, there must be a constraint .. a relation or something that is not verified and prompt the error, when can i get that SQLS profiler ? Thanks

Comment: @Joe - What edition of SQL Server do you have (e.g. Express, Standard)

Comment: Thanks Martin for your interest, I have SQL Server 2005 standard